# get the average of several SQL rows (a_ID and avg_data) in table A where in table B (a_ID is grouped by b_ID)

Tags: php, mysql, search, average

I have 2 tables. Table A, Table B.

```
Table A:

a_ID (313, 314, 315, 322) avg_data (50, 920, 12, 16)

Table B:

a_ID (313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323) 
b_ID (204, 204, 204, 205, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 210)
```

So multiple a_ID belong to one b_ID.

I want to get the average of avg_data in table A for all of the a_ID that belong to b_ID in table B. I am trying to do this in php.

Something like:

```
 GET the list of a_ID in table B that have the same b_ID, then search table_A for all these ID's in the list and get the average of their respective avg_data column.
```

Is this possible to do just in one SQL statement?

So far I have tried

```
 $qry="SELECT b_ID
    FROM table_B";              

 $result= mysql_query($qry);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $[b_ID] =$row['b_ID'];
  }

  foreach($b_ID as $value) {

  $qry="SELECT a_ID
    FROM table_B WHERE b_ID = '$value'";                

  $result= mysql_query($qry);


  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $a_ID[] =$row['a_ID'];



   }

   $search = implode(', ', $a_ID); 

   echo $search; 

  }
```

So this should output

```
 313, 314, 315 <br> 316, 317 <br> 318 <br> 319 etc
```

but it actually outputs:

```
 313, 314, 315, 322, 313, 314, 315

 313, 314, 315, 322, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317

 313, 314, 315, 322, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318
```

This is meant to get a list of the a_ID's that belong to each b_ID so that I can then find the average, however, output is not correct and contains more a_ID's than it should.

I've tried to explain this as well as possible, but it doesnt seem to very good.

Comment: So which  `a_ID` from your example above should be included? You said _have the same b_ID_, which implies 1,2, each having b_ID=204.  But what if there are more sets of like pairs? Do you want all those where the two or more of any b_ID exist?

Comment: Table_A has 313,314,315,322 Table_B has 313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323 and 204,204,204,205,205,206,207,208,209,210,210

Comment: So for each Id in table A I need the average of them where they have the same b_ID, if that makes sense

Comment: That doesn't really clarify.  Using the set of a_ID you posted at the top 1,2,4,9, which of those should be in your output?

Comment: I will edit the question so it makes more snese

Comment: So you are looking for the avg from 313,314,315, _not_ 322 because 322 does not have b_ID=204?

Comment: No - Ultimately I want multiple average values for all the ID's that share the same b_ID. So the avg of 313, 314, 315, and also 322 (although this is only 1 value but it could have many values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - after comments I think I understand that your ultimate goal is the averages of `avg_data`.  This can be done in a single rather simple query performing an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables and grouping by `b_ID`.

```
SELECT
  Tableb.b_ID,
  AVG(TableA.avg_data) AS average
FROM
  TableB
  INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.a_ID = TableB.a_ID
GROUP BY TableB.b_ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/349ba/12

Now, if you also want the `a_ID` listed in the output, it gets a bit more complicated. You need to join the result of that as a subquery back against `TableB` to get the `a_ID` list, then they can be grouped via `GROUP_CONCAT()` into a comma-separated list of values which share the same average:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.a_ID), 
  avgs.average
FROM 
  TableB b
  /* Makes sure only a_ID existing in TableA appear in the output */
  INNER JOIN TableA a ON b.a_ID = a.a_ID
  INNER JOIN (
    /* Retrieves average avg_data for like b_ID values */
    SELECT
      Tableb.b_ID,
      AVG(TableA.avg_data) AS average 
    FROM
      TableB
      INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.a_ID = TableB.a_ID
    GROUP BY TableB.b_ID
  ) avgs ON b.b_ID = avgs.b_ID
GROUP BY avgs.b_ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/349ba/21

Comment: Thank for persevering, I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: @sleepysnake The second query is faulty because if two sets come out with the same average, they'll be incorrectly grouped. I'm removing it.

Comment: @sleepysnake Nevermid - fixed that with a different `GROUP BY`.

Comment: its working! I only needed the first query. Thank you so much

Comment: @sleepysnake Great. Hope the second was at least instructive then, cheers.

Comment: The second makes some sense, this is the first time I have used JOINS and GROUPS in SQL, well - the first time I have seen it being used. I'm gonna try and work out how to get each TableB.bID that the average was made from now.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going through your php code ...

1. First use distinct in your first query ..
2. when you are creating $a_ID you need to keep them grouped according to the b_id ..

I have done some changes in your code ..please have a look

```
 <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('test');

        $qry="SELECT distinct b_ID
            FROM Table_B";              

         $result= mysql_query($qry);

         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $b_ID[] =$row['b_ID'];
          }


          foreach($b_ID as $value) {

          $qry="SELECT a_ID
            FROM yable_B WHERE b_ID = '$value'";                

          $result= mysql_query($qry);


          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

              $a_ID[$value][] =$row['a_ID'];



           }
          }   


          foreach( $a_ID as $value)
           {
             $search = implode(',',$value);
             echo $search ."<br>"; 
           }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct b_ID, (select avg(avg_data) from table_A where a_ID in (select a_ID   from table_B y where y.b_ID=x.b_ID) ) from table_B x`